# jQuery - nextAll() selector for Parent-Child-Sub Child

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<option data-task-hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task 1 </option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="5"> -  - Child task 2</option>
```

jQuery to fetch child of `Parent Task`

```
var selectedOption = $('#dropDownId option:selected')
var selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.data('task-hours');
var sum = 0;
selectedOption.nextAll().each(function(){
    if (sum < selectedOptionValue) {
        sum += $(this).data('task-hours');
    } else {
        sum = selectedOptionValue;
        return false;
    }
});
```

This gives the total value of child task(s) under `Parent Task`.  If then I need to add sub-child under a `Child Task 1` desired HTML would be

```
<option data-task-hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task 1 </option>
<option data-task-hours="25" value="3"> -  -  - Sub Child task 1.1</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="5"> -  - Child task 2</option>
```

`nextAll()` would fetch all the subsequent options under any selected option from doprdown. How can I know if `Child Task 1` has a `Sub Child task 1.1` under it considering Parent-Child-Sub-child relationship ?

Comment: There isn't any markup on the hierarchy, so you'll have to parse the HTML text and build a tree to find out what is under what. I'd use JavaScript DOM to *generate* the `option` tags and then you'll get the tree you want for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add attributes for parent-child hierarchy like,

Use data-parent attribute for the children who is child of any parent option for example, `data-parent="value of parent option"` (data-parent="2")

So the html looks like,

```
<option data-task-hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task 1 </option>
<option data-task-hours="25" value="3" data-parent="2"> -  -  - Sub Child task 1.1</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="5"> -  - Child task 2</option>
```

Now, you need to pass the `data-parent` attribute in [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) like,

```
selectedOption.nextAll("[data-parent='"+selectedOption.val()+"']").each(function(){
    if (sum < selectedOptionValue) {
        sum += $(this).data('task-hours');
    } else {
        sum = selectedOptionValue;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Rohan Kumar: Changed my html structure as you said above. when I alert `[data-parent='"+selectedOption.value+"']` it says `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry it should be `selectedOption.val()`. Try my updated answer

Comment: 1) Should the `data-parent` attrbitue added to all select option elements of only to sub-child i.e. child of child?

2) If `data-parent` is added to all options, it stikll counts all the elements under a Child Task rather than sub-child

Comment: `data-parent` should be added only for the child elements. And a condition `[data-parent='"+selectedOption.val()+"']` will get only the next child elements only.

Comment: For eg: for `Parent > Child > Sub-Child` tree, should data parent be added only for `Sub-Child` ?

Comment: If you want to add task-hours for sub-child then you can add, otherwise add parent value of child element only. You can add one more attribute like `data-grand_parent="grand parent value"`.

Comment: Thus, to add parent value of child element, we can add data-attribute to both `child and sub-child` as both have parents

Comment: If you add `parent` and `grand_parent` then you can loop twice for both so it is way to add task-hours fro both child and sub0child element.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9fq958j/1/) You can get total task hours :

```
var selectedOption = $('#dropDownId option:selected')
var selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.data('task-hours');
var sum = 0;
var currentLevel = selectedOption.text().split('-').length;
selectedOption.nextAll("option").each(function() {
    if(this.text.split('-').length > currentLevel){
         if (sum < selectedOptionValue) {
           sum += $(this).data('task-hours');
        } else {       
           sum = selectedOptionValue;
           return false;
       }
    }
   });

console.log(sum);
```